# Finding the range of $\cos t\sqrt{2-\cos^2 3t}$ via "elementary" (ie, pre-calculus) methods

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

I was wondering, what would be a precalculus level solution to the following question:

> What is the range of the function $x(t)=\cos t\sqrt{2-\cos^2 3t} \ $, for $\ t\in[0,2\pi)$ ?

Please note that I am stressing "*precalculus level*". I know very well how to do this using the usual first-second derivative criteria for [stationary points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point) of a single variable, real valued function. However, my main motivation for the question is my attempt to explain it to precalculus-level students. (Their exposition to calculus is limited to the notions of limits, continuity and the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) for continuous functions. There have been no derivatives in the picture so far.)

Thanks in advance!

**P.S.:** Note, that the corresponding problem would appear far easier for the $\sin t\sqrt{2-\cos^2 3t}$, $t\in[0,2\pi)$ function: the range can be easily found to be $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$ by appealing to the intermediate value theorem for continuous functions and taking into account that the factors $\sin t$ and $\sqrt{2-\cos^2 3t}$ acquire their extreme values for the same value of the parameter $t$. However, this is not the case for $\cos t\sqrt{2-\cos^2 3t}$.

Comment: Why think that a precalculus is possible?

Comment: @John Coleman, i was just wondering whether it is possible or not. So i thought it might be a good idea, asking the community.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't got a solution but a possible approach.

If you can exploit symmetry it should be possible to maximise $x(t)$ just by maximising $x(t)^2$.

Via the change of variables $\gamma=\cos^2t$, it should be possible to show that

$$x(t)^2=\frac13\gamma(1-\gamma)(4\gamma-1).$$

> If it can be shown without calculus that the maximum of this occurs at 
>   $\displaystyle\gamma_0=\frac{7+\sqrt{33}}{6}$,

then I believe you can work backwards to show that $x(t)^2$ and thus $x(t)$ are maximised at

$$t_0=\cos^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\gamma_0}\right).$$

Comment: thank you for the feedback. But how can we determine the extrema of $x^2(t)=\frac13\gamma(1-\gamma)(4\gamma-1)$ without calculus?

Comment: @KonKan I have no idea.